# Xcode 15 linker fails with undefined symbols but no symbols listed

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors

I am rebuilding a project that was list build 2 years ago after upgrading to Xcode 15. Build fails with the following message:
...

Undefined symbols:

Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

...

I have added -v to my linker flags and still setting the same message. Any ideas?

Comment: I had a similar problem, perhaps this solution would work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/77208597/22660286

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, and what solved it for me was adding the `-l64` linker flag in OTHER_LDFLAGS (which tells Xcode to use the old linker)