# Xcode 15 update broke flutter iOS app: duplicate symbols (no symbols listed)

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, macos, xcode15

I am working on a flutter app for iOS, using Mac mini with Apple M1.

The app worked fine on the simulator and real device until today, when I updated Xcode to 15.0.

Now, I cannot run on a simulator or a real device, getting the following error:

```
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Error (Xcode): 2 duplicate symbols

Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Error launching application on XXXXXX’s iPhone.
```

Instead of the above error, I sometimes (randomly?) get the error described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77181136/xcode-15-linker-fails-with-undefined-symbols-but-no-symbols-listed).

What I tried:

1. Verified with Flutter Doctor everything is OK (initially, the Xcode installation did not complete, missing the command line tools, but I fixed that)
2. Upgraded flutter (3.13.6)
3. Updated cocoa pods (1.13.0), ([as instructed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77136958/flutter-or-react-native-xcode-15-error-xcode-dt-toolchain-dir-cannot-be-used), this fixed an earlier error I was getting `DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, use TOOLCHAIN_DIR instead`)
4. Cleared the Xcode cache ([as instructed here](https://www.enigmasoftware.com/how-to-clean-the-xcode-cache-and-prevent-xcode-crashes/)), deleted flutter sub-folders & files (.symlinks, Pods, Podfile.lock, pubspec.lock) and reinstalled pod ([as instructed here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/729712)), and ran flutter clean
5. Uninstalled and reinstalled Xcode
6. Created a new user on the Mac, installed Xcode and flutter from scratch, and cloned my app's Git repo from scratch
7. Tried building another ios app

Unfortunately, none of these resolved the error described above.

Any help or ideas would be most welcomed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done the following, and I guess one or more have resolved this:

1. Created a new user on the Mac
2. Installed Xcode and Flutter from scratch, as instructed [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos)
3. Still got duplicate symbols error. So tried to downgrade the iOS, which failed and thus forced me to restore to factory settings
4. Set other link flags add "-ld64", a instructed [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/731089)
5. Now I was getting another error `Cycle inside Runner; building could produce unreliable results. Cycle details: → Target 'Runner': ExtractAppIntentsMetadata ○ Target 'Runner' has copy command from`, so I in Xcode>Targets>Runner>Build Phases, I dragged "Embed Framework", "[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks", and "Embed App Extentions" to be before "Run Script" as instructed [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/730974)

I can now build and run the app using Xcode 15 on a real device (iOS 16.7). Haven't tried yet on a simulator

Comment: The one thing that fixed it for me was "Set other link flags add "-ld64", a instructed here". Thanks!

Comment: Step 3 worked for me. I can finally build in xcode 15

Answer (score 0):

Please make this changes on your project

Open Project in Xcode -

- go to POD section
- Open Target Support Files
- Open Pod-Runner
- Open Pods-Runner-frameworks

Update this line

Existing - `source="$(readlink "${source}")"`

New - `source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"`

Comment: Thank you Chirag for this very detailed instructions! The file already had the new version: source="$(readlink -f "${source}")". Do you have any other ideas? Would be greatly appreciated!